# Sokoban game: move boxes automatically

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I have already implemented a functionallity, when keeper automatically moves using breadth first search algorithm. Now I want it to move boxes automatically as well (if keeper can move box from source to destination without moving another boxes). How to I do it? I've tried modifying BFS, not haven't yet succeed.

**UPDATE:** I don't need to solve the puzzle. Instead I want to develop handy user-interface, when user can move boxes with their mouse. For this I need some algo, which would allow to compute move sequence. But it's only about moving single box and if only no other boxes should be moved in order to do so.

Comment: What is the specific problem you are having (besides the broad "it does not work")?

Comment: It solves simple routes well (when box path contains each location only once). But there are also a complex case, when box steps on each location more than once (e.g. you move a box into wide area to reposition keeper and then moves box back by the same path). I believe I should store not only if particular location is visited, but also where was the keeper at the moment).

Comment: I was more asking if there are some algorithms which people has already developed for the task. I don't know, if my approach will be pushes/moves optimal, while I would definetely like it to be optimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use breadth-first search as before (or A* if you prefer), but search the appropriate set of states.

When you are searching for a path for the keeper, the states correspond to the squares in the grid. But when you are searching for a way for the keeper to move a block, the states correspond to *pairs* of squares in the grid (one for the keeper, one for the block).

Here's the smallest non-trivial example. Suppose we have a Sokoban level with squares labelled as follows:

[image: Sokoban level with squares numbered 1 to 6]

The grid contains the keeper and one block. The state space consists of pairs of squares occupied by the keeper and the block. There are 56 such states, drawn as small circles in the diagram below.

[image: state space with 56 states]

The lines show possible transitions within this state space. The thin lines correspond to moves by the keeper (and are bidirectional). The heavy lines correspond to pushing the block (hence go in one direction only). It is *this* state space that you need to search.

For example, if the block starts at 7 and the keeper at 8, then the keeper can push the block to 8 by following the red path in the state space:

[image: non-trivial path in state space]

Note that along this path, the block goes through the positions 7–6–5–6–7–8. You couldn't have found this path by just considering positions for the block, as the block passes through positions 6 and 7 twice.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. Could you share, how did you do those nice illustrations?

Comment: You're welcome. I made the diagrams using [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/).

Comment: Also algorithm will include modified BFS on the map to find out, if keeper could reach it's position in a modified map. BFS will be modified, because position of one of the blocks (moved one) will be different.

Answer (score 3):

From [Wikipedia - Sokoban](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokoban):

> Sokoban can be studied using the theory of computational complexity.
>   The problem of solving Sokoban puzzles has been proven to be
>   NP-hard.[3](http://www.claymath.org/millennium/) This is also interesting for artificial intelligence
>   researchers, because solving Sokoban can be compared to designing a
>   robot which moves boxes in a warehouse. Further work has shown that
>   solving Sokoban problems is also PSPACE-complete.[4]
>
> Sokoban is difficult not only due to its branching factor (which is
>   comparable to chess), but also its enormous search tree depth; some
>   levels require more than 1000 "pushes". Skilled human players rely
>   mostly on heuristics; they are usually able to quickly discard futile
>   or redundant lines of play, and recognize patterns and subgoals,
>   drastically cutting down on the amount of search.
>
> **Some Sokoban puzzles can be solved automatically by using a
>   single-agent search algorithm, such as IDA*, enhanced by several
>   techniques which make use of domain-specific knowledge.[5]** This is the
>   method used by Rolling Stone, a Sokoban solver developed by the
>   University of Alberta GAMES Group. The more complex Sokoban levels
>   are, however, out of reach even for the best automated solvers.

Is this what you wanted to know?

Incidentally, solving Sokoban puzzles in a provably optimal way is [NP-hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem), which means there's a [$1,000,000 prize](http://www.claymath.org/millennium/) waiting for you if you figure out how to do it.